# User/Auth object in Android - where does it belong: ViewModel, MainActivity, extended Application object, or someplace else

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am struggling on the guidance around how we manage objects with global scope when using fragments. I have a user/auth object and need it in almost every fragment as it is required for calling webapis. Normally I try to use ViewModels but that seems like a 1 per fragment (or shared by multiple fragments as in master/detail) is the recommendation. So the idea that a AuthViewModel is instantiated in each fragment does not seem right. I could keep a user object in the fragment and use it for authentication or use it in an extended Application object.

1. Create a AuthViewModel with a authobject and use it in each fragment
2. Store the authobject in the MainActivity and use it in each fragment as required
3. Extend the Application object so it can be used by each fragment

Or is there another option?

I need the object in case a call fails so that I can refresh the access token or even the user if their token has expired.

Answer (score 0):

If it is simply Auth related object, I usually prefer to keep it below the business layer, ViewModel and Fragments/Activities should have no reason to deal with low-level objects. Preferably this object should exist on the network layer or even better an Auth Layer that sits on top of the network layer, which can be a singleton and be shared among those that need it.

Comment: It is an object representing the user which has tokens and it needs to refresh periodically. It also holds the user alias which will be visible on screens and an guid which will be inserted into records which are created and the tokens are used to call web apis. It is information from Azure AD B2C. What do you mean on the network layer?

Comment: By network layer I meant if you had simple Auth, something like unregistered OAuth2.0, you can make a layer, that can get injected at a repository level. A good way to structure your code is in logical sections, User Profile can be logical separation and you can have data providing interfaces, this User Profile can be injected at a repository level (repository can be a singleton), and repository can be injected to all ViewModels that need it. And all your ViewModels will use the same Repository and by that extension use the same Profile Object.